# Several positive wires, one negative?

Tags: voltage, power, automotive

I'll be fixing a motorcycle soon, trying to know if it's possible to have two or more positive wires (connected directly to the battery terminal) but only one negative.

There is a usb converter AND an auxiliary light, hence the need for two positive wires.

Let's say the wires are rated for the current draw that will be used, so there is no further margin for a direct and more simple one positive one negative for both. Will the negative wire have overcurrent problems?

Comment: Is negative also attached to the cycle frame and hence also forms a return path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could use one wire to ground while using multiple wires from V+. This is normal. All you need to make sure is your ground wire is sized for the total current across it, in terms of voltage drop and heat. Use a voltage drop calculator online to figure out what size wire you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, somehow it seemed to me that only the positive one should be sized, the water pipe comparison hits home so accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Your needed wire gauge is mainly dependent on the maximum amperage you expect to draw within that circuit. Usually, many of your electronics will be grounded to the frame/chassis, and the battery's negative terminal will already have an adequate-sized lead from it tied to the chassis for your return "ground" connection.

If I know how much the maximum expected amperage draw, then I usually judge the next wire-gauge size (or two) larger than what the circuit calls for. In this case though, your chassis ground is probably already sufficient.